# Add speaker annotation (say id, name) to cloud-speech-to-text api and get it included in the output json produced by the cloud-speech-to-text api

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google cloud platform's Cloud speech-to-text api converts multiple speaker audio to text. It returns a JSON output which includes who said what at what time. But the speaker identification **(WHO)** is anonymous. Is there a way to annotate or give the input about speaker (say id, name) and get it included in the output JSON produced by the api?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices#speech_transcribe_diarization_beta-protocol),There is no way to input speaker information to Cloud speech to text api.

As you know, Speaker diarization function only distinguishes speakers by number at the `speakerTag` value.

```
"words": [
            {
              "startTime": "0s",
              "endTime": "1.100s",
              "word": "hi",
              "speakerTag": 2
            },
            {
              "startTime": "1.100s",
              "endTime": "2s",
              "word": "I'd",
              "speakerTag": 2
            }
```

I think the only way you can workaround is modifying `Speakertag` value of JSON output manually .